# Filtering simple Flatlist

Tags: reactjs, react-native, search, react-native-flatlist

I want to filter this simple flatlist through a search bar. How do I code it so that whatever I write something on the input text it filters the flatlist? Could you help me completing it?

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, SafeAreaView, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, LayoutAnimation, Image, FlatList, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
import {ListItem, SearchBar} from 'react-native-elements';

export default class HomeScreen extends React.Component{
   render() {
       return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.header}>
                <Text style={styles.headerTitle}>Home</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.container1}>
                <Icon name={"ios-search"} style={styles.icon}/>       
                <TextInput style={styles.inputBox}
                          underlineColorAndroid='rgba(0,0,0,0)' 
                          placeholder="Procura aqui"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
                          placeholderTextColor = "white"
                          selectionColor="black"
                          keyboardType="default"              
                          />
             </View> 
             <View style={styles.flatlist}>
              <FlatList
                data = {[
                  {key:'Tiago'},
                  {key:'Ricardo'},
                  {key:'Beatriz'},
                  {key:'Miguel'},
                  {key:'Simão'},
                  {key:'David'}
                ]}
                renderItem={({item}) => <Text style={styles.item}>{item.key}</Text>}
              />
             </View>
    </View>           
    );
}
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should have a state value for searchtext and filter the array based on that. the component should be as below.

```
export default class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      searchText: '',
    };
  }

  render() {
    //Data can be coming from props or any other source as well
    const data = [
      { key: 'Tiago' },
      { key: 'Ricardo' },
      { key: 'Beatriz' },
      { key: 'Miguel' },
      { key: 'Simão' },
      { key: 'David' },
    ];

    const filteredData = this.state.searchText
      ? data.filter(x =>
          x.key.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.searchText.toLowerCase())
        )
      : data;
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.header}>
          <Text style={styles.headerTitle}>Home</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.container1}>
          <Icon name={'ios-search'} style={styles.icon} />
          <TextInput
            style={styles.inputBox}
            underlineColorAndroid="rgba(0,0,0,0)"
            placeholderTextColor="white"
            selectionColor="black"
            keyboardType="default"
            onChangeText={text => this.setState({ searchText: text })}
            value={this.state.searchText}
          />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.flatlist}>
          <FlatList
            data={filteredData}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
              <Text style={styles.item}>{item.key}</Text>
            )}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It was really helpfull! What if want to add an image to each key? How do I associate it?

Comment: Same thing but your data array would have another property like image or imageurl and you can render it in your flatlist render item

Comment: For example, in the data array I add "key: Tiago, image: *name of the image*.png" right?

Comment: should be the url of the image then 
renderItem={({ item }) => (
             <View>  <Text style={styles.item}>{item.key}</Text><Image src={{uri:item.image}}/>
</View>
            )}

Comment: image should be url or you should require the image and then use it, check the format in the doc https://reactnative.dev/docs/images

Comment: but the above code is not letting to type completely it is running for each letter which is refreshing the flatlist how to avoid this any suggestions ? @GuruparanGiritharan

Comment: @LRajk if you have a requirement to search more than one letter then you can update the state then check the length and update the filter

Comment: is there any way so that user can type smoothly and flatlist filter items smoothly no refreshing again and again because refreshing cause the keyboard disappears whenever the user input single letter @GuruparanGiritharan

Comment: @LRajk keyboard should be open throughout, maybe its a different issue, better post a separate question

Answer (score 0):

Please provide flatlist data from the state so you can control it while searching. Assuming if you want to bring those results at the top that matches your search text, you can do something like the below code. Firstly add `onChangeText` prop to the textinput and handle the input like this.

```
filterItems = (search_text) => {

var items = [...this.state.data];

var filtered = [];

if (search_text.length > 0) {
  filtered = items.sort(
    (a, b) => b.includes(search_text) - a.includes(search_text),
  );

  this.setState({data: filtered});
} else {
  filtered = items.sort((a, b) => b - a);

  this.setState({data: filtered});
}
```

};